# Why do i have problems when the input is directed to be saved in a integer variable when coding in C?

Tags: c, netbeans

I'm learning to code on C, and i get this problem when i run the program.

/cygdrive/C/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0.2/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33:   696 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}"

here is the code

```
int main() {

int edad1,edad2;
char nombre1[30],nombre2[30];
float promedio;
printf("Introduzca el primer nombre \n");
gets(nombre1);

printf("Introduzca la primer edad \n");
scanf("%d",edad1);

printf("Introduzca el segundo nombre \n");
gets(nombre2);

printf("Introduzca la segunda edad \n");
scanf("%d", edad2);

promedio = (edad1 +edad2)/2.0;

printf("El primer nombre es: \n %d \n y su edad es: \n El segundo nombre es: "
        "%d \n y su edad es: \n %d \n\n El promedio es: %f" , nombre1 ,edad1,nombre2,edad2,promedio);


return (0);
```

}

it runs well at first, receives the string, but when i enter an integer it crashes, it may be a problem with the compiler, i'm using the GNU CC compiler, i get the same error when i compile it on netbeans.

Comment: `scanf("%d",edad1);` --> `scanf("%d", &edad1);`

Comment: Remove the `c++` tag - `c++` and `c` are 2 distinct (but related) programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to scanf:

```
scanf("%d", &edad1);
```

Also, in your last printf() you output nombre1 with %d which is wrong. It should be %s since nombre1 is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
promedio = ((float)(edad1 +edad2))/2.0;
printf("El primer nombre es: %s \n y su edad es: %d\n El segundo nombre es: %s \n y su edad es: %d \n\n El promedio es: %f" , nombre1 ,edad1,nombre2,edad2,promedio);
```